# How do I reference a customised tabhost in a layout file

Tags: android, user-interface, android-framelayout, fragment-tab-host

I want to reference a customised `tabhost` class in a `fragmentblayout` file so that I can inflate it just like a standard `tabhost`.

The customised tabhost class is called "`FlingableTabHost`" and is almost a direct copy of Google's `FlingableTabHost`.  Please note that `ViewPager` is not a viable solution here as I need this `tabhost` to operate independently of its parent fragment, which has a `GridView` above it.

I originally had the `FlingableTabHost` as a `static` class of the parent fragment, but I changed it to its own class when I couldn't make it work.  Obviously I'm still having trouble.

My FlingableTabHost code looks like this -

```
public class FlingableTabHost extends TabHost {

    //instance variables
    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    Animation mRightInAnimation;
    Animation mRightOutAnimation;
    Animation mLeftInAnimation;
    Animation mLeftOutAnimation;

    //constructor - for creation from code
    public FlingableTabHost(Context aContext) {
    super(aContext);

    //call setup
    setupTabHost(aContext);
    }

    //constructor - for xml inflation
    public FlingableTabHost(Context aContext, AttributeSet aAttrs) {
    super(aContext, aAttrs);

    //call setup
    setupTabHost(aContext);
    }

    private void setupTabHost(Context aContext){.....}

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Obviously the setupTabHost method takes care of the "flingable" logic.

My layout xml for the fragment contains the following...

```
<myPackageName.FlingableTabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                style="@style/FullMatch" >
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                style="@style/FullMatch" >
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                style="@style/FullMatch" >
            </FrameLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</myPackageName.FlingableTabHost>
```

I know this shouldn't be hard.  Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Have you considered extending tabactivity instead?

Comment: I was given to understand putting a ViewPager inside a FragmentActivity was a better design than directly using TabActivity.  I've actually done this before, but it won't work for this solution.  The top 33% of the view needs to be static while the bottom 67% is tabbed.